# Fail to show the selected dropdown value from database in the form of a dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

It's for an edit page, 1st user has selected a value from the dropdown and it's saved to the database 
Now Iam trying to get the selected value from database and show it in the dropwdown as the selected one.
What's wrong with the code.

```html
<td><select name="agama" id="agama">
    <option value="open" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'open') echo ' selected="selected"'>open</option>
    <option value="closed" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'closed') echo ' selected="closed"'>closed</option>
</select></td>
```

To make sure i could get the value from the database, instead of showing the selected value in the form of a dropdown, i try to display them in an input field.

```
 <td><input type="text" name = "ds[]" class="ds" value="<?php echo $row['status'] ?>"></td>
```

And it worked , it correctly display the corresponding value from the database.

For some reason, i just couldn't get it to display in the form of a dropdown.
Any ideas guy?? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do like this `<option value="open" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'open') echo ' selected="selected"'>{{$row['status']}}</option>` in your td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like some syntax error.

```
<td><select name="agama" id="agama">
    <option value="open" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'open') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>open</option>
    <option value="closed" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'closed') echo ' selected="closed"'; ?>>closed</option>
</select></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close PHP **?>** .

TRY This-

```
<td><select name="agama" id="agama">
    <option value="open" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'open') echo ' selected="selected"' ?> > open</option>
    <option value="closed" <?php if ($row['status'] === 'closed') echo ' selected="closed"'?> >closed</option>
</select></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script :

```html
   <td><select name="agama" id="agama">
   <option value="open"<?php $row['status'] == 'open' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>Open</option>
   <option value="closed"<?php $row['status'] == 'closed' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>Closed</option>
</select></td>
```